# Obj C Initializer Declaration

Tags: objective-c

Very new to Obj-C and very confused about the syntax of the .h and .m files. All I'm trying to do is pass an array into my initializer. I get an error on my .h file that says `Expected a type` and a warning on my .m file that says `Conflicting parameter types in implementation of initWithColor': '__strong id' vs 'GLKVector4' (aka 'union _GLKVector4')`

Square.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Square : NSObject

- (id) initWithColor : (GLKVector4) col;

@end
```

Square.m

```
#import "Square.h"
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

#define BG_WIDTH 500.0f
#define BG_HEIGHT 400.0f

typedef struct {
    GLKVector3 positionCoordinates;
    GLKVector2 textureCoordinates;
    GLKVector3 normalCoordinates;
} VertexData;

VertexData bgRect[] = {
    { { 0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f}, },   // 2D - forward facing only
    { { BG_WIDTH,  0.0f,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f} },
    { { 0.0f,  BG_HEIGHT,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f} },
    { { 0.0f,  BG_HEIGHT,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f} },
    { { BG_WIDTH,  0.0f,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f} },
    { { BG_WIDTH,  BG_HEIGHT,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f} },};

@implementation Square {
    GLKVector4 color;
}

- (id) initWithColor : (GLKVector4) col {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        color = col;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>` into Square.h, since you're referencing `GLKVector4` in that file.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a guess. .

Your code looks fine, I think its just a matter of doing the following:

- Make sure you link to the GLKit framework.
- Add the import to your header file #import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

[image]

**Unrelated aside:**

By the way, by modern objective-c conventions, its considered good practice to underscore your ivar names, as follows:

```
@implementation Square {
    GLKVector4 _color;
}
```

In either Xcode or AppCode you can rename a symbol (ivar, property, etc) from the Refactor menu.

Comment: Did you read the second point? It said "Add the import to your header file #import <GLKit/GLKit.h>"